Adding private link to app service adds new url to nslookup
My question is about existing functionality and if I have misconfigured a privatelink.
I have an app service that is publicly accessible. Let’s say with a custom domain name mytestsite.com so that points to mytestsite.azurewebsites.net.
This app service connects to databases and other external services that are on a vnet so I’ve enabled vnet between the app service and these other services. Now that I’ve done that, an nslookup to my public custom domain name includes the privatelink url that looks like mytestsite.privatelink.web.azurewebsites.com.
Our customer who connects to our public site via a custom domain has their own private network with privatelink dns zone from azure which are now conflicting with the privatelink url showing in our nslookup.
I can’t tell if there is a misconfiguration on our side or on their side or if adding an app service to a vnet is behaving as intended. Should it have the privatelink url in nslookup?

When you add a Private endpoint to App Service, the DNS entry for the App Service is updated to point to the canonical name mywebapp.privatelink.azurewebsites.net. This is expected behavior and is done to enable private endpoint connectivity to the App Service. If your customer has their own private network with a private DNS zone from Azure, and it is conflicting with the privatelink URL showing in your nslookup, it is likely that they have also added a private endpoint to their own resources.
You should work with your customer to ensure that the private DNS zones are set up correctly to avoid conflicts.
You can also consider adding a Private Endpoint in your customer's environment so that they too access your App Service via the Private Endpoint
Reference- Using Private Endpoints for App Service apps - DNS

Yeah, this is true. I just find it odd that MS wouldn't resolve to the public IP if the service isn't found in their private Azure DNS Zone. In the end I had to remove the privatelink from my public service since I wasn't connecting to it privately anyway. If I had been, I would have had to add AFD with the CNAME pointed to AFD.
